# Plotting a heat map of binary and continious values

Tags: r, heatmap

I have this matrix of pathway analysis. Genes in each pathway gets 1 if not 0. I also have fold change for genes. I tried to plot this but fold change being confused with absence and pretense of genes like :

[image]

I have tried

```
heatmap(m)

dput(m)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, -0.903826171835163, -0.247705285294349, -0.401239527828149, 
-1.20189443333319, -0.758305343685411, -1.10106389326754, -0.585488441571586, 
-0.610209849183418, -1.28841166063443, -1.2443689942311, -0.44380661806954, 
-0.393767679922636, -0.9865911233588, -1.16638985537113, -0.846196153682942, 
-1.08069734237831, -0.585488441571586, -0.501442757103725, -1.09515274600357, 
-1.28841166063443, -0.758305343685411, -0.358909656766957, -0.435604213681894, 
-0.233037798755743, -0.401239527828149, -1.28841166063443, -0.563163557390339, 
-1.08069734237831, -0.247705285294349, -0.903826171835163, -0.9865911233588, 
0.377359646511066, 0.453386357728066, 1.70862112102298, 0.532342427101257, 
1.61935728655752, 1.15211775940032, 0.265720938549918, 0.420856476956162, 
0.377359646511066, 0.350765937539292, 0.276646264257092), .Dim = c(42L, 
8L), .Dimnames = list(c("CCL2", "CCL4", "CD40", "CLCF1", "CSF3", 
"CXCL5", "CXCL6", "CXCL8", "IL1B", "IL6", "IL6R", "LTB", "OSM", 
"TNFRSF1B", "TNFSF10", "FOS", "FOSL1", "MMP3", "PTGS2", "TNFAIP3", 
"BCL2A1", "BIRC3", "CFLAR", "DDX58", "GADD45B", "TIRAP", "EDN1", 
"SOCS3", "IGF2", "JAK1", "NR4A1", "CACNA1D", "CALML5", "CALML6", 
"CCNA2", "CCND2", "CDK6", "MAPK1", "RBL1", "CDC6", "CDKN2C", 
"SMC3"), c("Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction", "IL-17 signaling", 
"NF-kappa B signaling", "TNF signaling", "PI3K-Akt signaling", 
"Cellular senescence", "Cell cycle", "Log2FC")))

> head(m)
      Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction IL-17 signaling
CCL2                                       1               1
CCL4                                       1               0
CD40                                       1               0
CLCF1                                      1               0
CSF3                                       1               1
CXCL5                                      1               1
      NF-kappa B signaling TNF signaling PI3K-Akt signaling
CCL2                     0             1                  0
CCL4                     1             0                  0
CD40                     1             0                  0
CLCF1                    0             0                  0
CSF3                     0             0                  1
CXCL5                    0             1                  0
      Cellular senescence Cell cycle     Log2FC
CCL2                    0          0 -0.9038262
CCL4                    0          0 -0.2477053
CD40                    0          0 -0.4012395
CLCF1                   0          0 -1.2018944
CSF3                    0          0 -0.7583053
CXCL5                   0          0 -1.1010639
>
```

Can you help to solve this?

Comment: Not sure what you expect, but it seems it plots what you entered, with row normalization (i.e. `scale="row"`).

Answer (score 0):

heatmap(as.matrix(m[,1:7])) should do the trick.
[image]

Comment: But he mean having a heatmap showing both binary values and continuous column not just ignoring the continuous column